# SQL Sorting with multiple attributes (order by conformity)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table with certain attributes such as name and address. In a search field I want to let users of a system type in whatever they know about these people and return the results in a table. Obviously I do want the results that are fitting best to be on top.

1. Should the ranking be done in the SQL command or are there other ways that might work better?
2. Does anyone know a good way to order/rank the results based by highest conformity? I basically do want the person to show up on top that fits the search criteria most.

You can see an example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19e9ad

Thanks for your help!

(I do use SQL Server currently, but any help is appreciated.)

Comment: What is `highest conformity` ?

Comment: I just used that term to describe it a bit better. For me it means how well does the result fit keeping in mind that there are 5 attributes to check.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a string comparison function, such as Jaro-Winkler.  This is a built in function for Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm) and I would imagine many other RDBMs.

Comment: maybe you should explain what kind of search are you trying to do

Comment: @Joel I think that might be the best solution so far. Does this also work if a user types "city lastname" and I join the data "lastname city".
Does this function understand that the strings are just in wrong order (from what I can see in the documentation this is not the case) and normalize them before returning result?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza A user can search a person in a database based on attributes such as name, last name and address

Comment: @JKau Jaro-Winkler is pretty good at recognizing strings are just in the wrong order, and the score will reflect that.  Run some tests and see if it gives you the results you want, but I use it a lot in the work I do (marketing customer data integration).  I developed an API that essentially does this, but with a lot of added complexity, such as accounting for nick names, etc.

Comment: @JKau - I moved my comments to the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the full text indexes and searches - they have options for ranking that might do the job for you:

- [Fulltext index creation info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

... and searching functionality info:

- [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx)
- [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)

Alternatively you can also work on your own solution like parsing the user input and matching word-by-word, then boosting results that match more words, exact words ordering etc. But you will need to handle a number of cases yourself (like multi-word cities like 'New York' etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking for a string comparison function, such as Jaro-Winkler. This is a built in function for Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_match.htm) and I would imagine many other RDBMs.

Jaro-Winkler is pretty good at recognizing strings are just in the wrong order, and the score will reflect that. Run some tests and see if it gives you the results you want, but I use it a lot in the work I do (marketing customer data integration). I developed an API that essentially does this, but with a lot of added complexity, such as accounting for nick names, etc. The API is at http://matchbox.io/#match-api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sort in sql but the most common solution is you do the sort in your UI so dont have to request the data from db every time user change sort order.

looking for your you may want add a field to your query to show `comformity` something like

```
 SELECT *, function_comformity() as comformity
```

So you can do the sorting on your UI for that field as you do for name or zip code.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When sorting in UI: How do you sort there? Is there something you can suggest? (Even just a blog covering that)